# Linear fractional transformations in several variables?

Tags: reference-request, linear-fractional-transformation

Is there a general theory of functions of several variables that are linear fractional transformations in each variable separately, and treating their application to geometry of circles, spheres, tori, etc.?

For example:
$$
(w,x)\mapsto \frac{a+bw+cx+dwx}{e+fw+gx+hwx}
$$